# Do Powershell conditional operators support search in arrays of object?

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, conditional-operator

I need to check if array of objects contains particular object via **-in** and **-contain** operators, but no luck, for example:

```
PS C:\> ($3_devices = Get-MobileDevice -ResultSize 3).guid

Guid                                
----                                
25c2f857-0098-46c3-b965-f22008006d16
1cc13103-3b36-4b69-ab51-b7e381453326
aae35123-4695-40b4-b6e5-7ea6cd0713c2


PS C:\> ($1_device = Get-MobileDevice -Resultsize 2 | select -last 1).guid

Guid                                
----                                
1cc13103-3b36-4b69-ab51-b7e381453326

PS C:\> $1_device -in $3_devices
False

PS C:\> $3_devices -contains $1_device
False

PS C:\> $3_devices.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------  
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array


PS C:\> $1_device.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     PSObject                                 System.Object
```

Where is a mistake or do PS conditional operators support objects?

Thanks.

Comment: try `$3_devices.guid -contains $1_device.guid`

Comment: Gert, it works but I need to compare the whole objects or use **several** _-and_ operators to compare objects by several parameters. But using a lot of _-and_ seems excessive. 
So, I'd like to use _-in_ or _-contains_ or understand why it doesn't work.
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to compare by reference you can just do `$3_devices -contains $1_device` (if the are actually the same object). If you want something like a "custom" comparison by specific parameters, you would have to write that yourself of course. But we don't even know what your objects look like.

Comment: @ДенисКвочка I assumed the guid is an unique identifier for the device. If it is you need no more comparisons.

Comment: @marsze, it doesn't work, please, look at the given examples above. 'My objects' in my example are mobile devices in Exchange OnLine. So, they are not  custom objects.

Comment: @Gert Jan Kraaijeveld, I've provided guid as evidence that object are the same, in my case I showed that 1cc13103-3b36-4b69-ab51-b7e381453326 is alredy a member of $3_devices array.

Answer (score 0):

"Contains" only works on arrays of objects when one of the following conditions is met:

1) The array contains objects of a type implemented with interfaces of IComparable and/or IEquatable. Lee Holmes has a great [blog post about this.](https://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2007/12/05/powershells-eq-operator-reference-equality-vs-value-equality/)

Example: the object type returned from Get-Service, [System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController], doesn't have one of those interfaces, so '-contains' won't work even though the objects appear identical:

```
$services = Get-Service
$service  = Get-Service -Name 'Spooler'

$service.GetType().GetInterfaces()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                                                                                                 
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                                                                                                 
True     False    IComponent                                                                                                                                                        
True     False    IDisposable        

$services -contains $service
False
```

2) Your comparison object has [reference equality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators) with an object in the array--they're actually stored in the same place in memory.

Your example, where you retrieve the array and the comparison object using two different commands, results in duplicate objects stored in different places in memory. If you had instead assigned the comparison object out of the array to a new variable ([by reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ref), by default) and compared against that, it should work:

```
$services = Get-Service
$service  = $services[0]

$service.GetType().IsValueType
False

$services -contains $service
True
```

Although this isn't particularly useful as a solution.

My recommendation: if you want to match two different reference objects by a number of properties but not all of them, here's a concise, quick solution that doesn't use multiple '-and' conditions:

```
$services = Get-Service

$serviceToMatch = Get-Service -Name 'Spooler' | Select -First 1

$propertiesToMatch = @('Status','StartType')

$propertiesToMatch | ForEach { $services = $services.Where({$_.$Input -eq $serviceToMatch.$Input}) }

$services | Select Name, Status, StartType | Sort Name
```

This results in a list of services matching the same 'Status' and 'StartType' as the 'Spooler' service.

Alternatively, you could create a custom hashtable of property names to match against:

```
$services = Get-Service

$serviceToMatch = @{
    Status    = 'Stopped'
    StartType = 'Automatic'
}

$serviceToMatch.Keys | ForEach { $services = $services.Where({$_.$Input -eq $serviceToMatch.$Input}) }

$services | Select Name, Status, StartType | Sort Name
```